# Web-scraping only a specific domain

Tags: html, web, screen-scraping, jsoup, scraper

I am trying to make a web scrpper that, for this example, scrapes news articles from Reuters.com. I want to get the title and date. I know I will ultimately just have to pull the source code from each address and then parse the HTML using something like JSoup.

My question is: How do I ensure I do this for each news article on Reuters.com? How do I know I have hit all the reuters.com addresses? Is there any APIs that can help me with this?

Comment: The short answer is that you keep scraping until the number of new URL discoveries you make (compared to the number of old ones) tends towards zero. There is no way you can determine how many articles reuters.com is hosting, unless they use a simple indexed article code in their URLs. Unfortunately, many newspaper sites use a complex URI scheme and are rarely concise or elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is called web scraping plus web crawling. What you have to do is visit every link matching some criteria (crawling) and then scrape the content (scraping). I've never used them but here are two java frameworks for the job

1. http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial
2. https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/

Of course you will have to use jsoup (or simillar) for parsing the content after you've collected the urls

**Update**
Check this out [Sending cookies in request with crawler4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536557/sending-cookies-in-request-with-crawler4j) for a better list of crawlers. Nutch is pretty good, but very complicated if the only thing you want is to crawl one site. crawler4j is very simple but I don't know if it supports cookies (and if that matters to you it's a deal breaker).

Comment: Great, thank you. Do you have any experience using either of these frameworks (I'm assuming I'd use only one or the other, correct?)?

Comment: As I mention in the post, unfortunately I don't. I will use one, in a project that I have (scrapper) to add crawling, but that will be in some time, so I haven't checked them. Yes you will use one of them. I believe the second one, is the simplest. Please don't forget to accept the answer if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this website `http://scrape4me.com/`

I was able to generate this url for headline: `http://scrape4me.com/api?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.reuters.com%2F&head=head&elm=&item[][DIV.topStory]=0&ch=ch`